# Navigation Controller doesn't show the title while working with TabBar Controller(Programmatically)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using a **navigationController** as the **window.rootViewController**. And as the **rootViewController** of **navigationController**, I'm using a tabBarController. But when I run the app, the title of the navigationBar is not showing up *(My Tabbar Controller shows up and I'm being able to see my viewController. No problem about that)*. I've tried to name the navigationBar in every viewController of the tabBar with using both of the code below in the viewDidload, but still nothing changed.

```
 navigationController?.title = "title"
 navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "title"
```

I've set the navigationController with tabbar in the SceneDelegete as below:

```
let countriesTabbarController = TabBarControllerBuilder.build()
    
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: countriesTabbarController)
    
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

How can I show my navigationController title for every viewController of the tabBar?

Comment: The problem is that you are putting the tab bar controller in a nav controller. That's wrong. Each tab should have its own nav controller.

Answer (score 2):

Each view controller has a property called `navigationItem` of type `UINavigationItem`. If you set its `title`, it will show up in the navigation bar if one exists.

For example in `viewDidLoad`, add this:

```
self.navigationItem.title = "title"
```

In other words: The title is set on the view controller contained in a navigation controller stack, not the navigation controller itself. Also not on the navigation bar, which probably also has a good reason I can't recall at the moment.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem

Comment: Thanks for responding. self.navigationItem.title = "title" is not working as well. I would say I don't have the navigationController but I can navigate between controllers using navigationController

Comment: The nav bar takes its title from the VC's title property, so set that.

Comment: Even simpler, in the view controller's `viewDidLoad` or an `init`, set the view controller's title directly: `self.title = "Some Title"`.